# Creating a point a certain angle from another

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a point A, I also have the angle.
I also have the distance from point A to point B.
What I want to do is create point B a certain angle away from point A.
Im a bit of a maths idiot so any help would be great.

Comment: you can't have an angle "away from point A" angles are between lines, so what you are missing is the line or direction the angle "goes away from"

Comment: You should upvote helpful answers and if you wish, you can award an accepted answer by clicking the tick next to the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your point will be this one:

```
NSPoint PointB = NSMakePoint(PointA.x + distance * sin(angle), 
                             PointA.y + distance * cos(angle));
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be NSPoint PointB = NSMakePoint(PointA.x + distance * cos(angle), PointA.y + distance * sin(angle)

Comment: Depends on where you assume the angle to go from.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Only problem I had with it was I had to convert my angle from degrees into radians in my method but other than it works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Bx=Ax+distance*cos(angle)

By=Ay+distance*sin(angle)

Comment: Thanks for this. Only problem I had with it was I had to convert my angle from degrees into radians in my method but other than it works great. Thanks!